# Not able to call web service protected by gatekeeper- keycloak via ajax request

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper, louketo-proxy

I have webservice protected by gatekeeper(louketo-proxy). When I call protected service via ajax request it won't redirect me to login page. It's showing me message "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:3000/app-name/api/getSession. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)."

Below is the gatekeeper configuration file:

```
client-id: app_id
client-secret: app_secret
discovery-url: http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/app_realm
redirection-url: http://127.0.0.1:3000
upstream-url: http://127.0.0.1:8043
enable-logging: true
enable-json-logging: true
verbose: true
enable-session-cookies: true
skip-upstream-tls-verify: true
skip-openid-provider-tls-verify: true
encryption-key: enc_key
listen: 0.0.0.0:3000
secure-cookie: false
enable-logging: true
enable-json-logging: true
enable-refresh-tokens: true
enable-session-cookies: true
enable-cors: true
cors-max-age : 1000 
cors-headers:
  - Accept
  - Content-Type
  - Cache-Control
  - Pragma
  - X-Custom-Header
  - Source
debug: true
resources:
  - uri: /app/api/v5/stylesheets/key=CSS
    white-listed: true
  - uri: /app/api/v5/images/key=FAVICON
    white-listed: true
  - uri: /app/api/v5/*
```

Keycloak version which I am using is 10.0.2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to define some allowed CORS origins, like

```
cors-origins:
  - '*'
```

to try out what happens if you allow everything?

Comment: I have also tried this. But not able to redirect me to keycloak auth login page. Although i am able to see the request in the browser network tab

Comment: Did you try to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin for cors-headers as well?

Comment: cors-origins:
  - '*'
cors-headers:
  - Accept
  - Content-Type
  - Cache-Control
  - Pragma
  - X-Custom-Header
  - Source
  - Origin
  - X-Requested-With
  - Access-Control-Request-Method
  - Access-Control-Request-Headers
  - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
  - Authorization
cors-methods:
  - GET
  - POST
  - PUT
  - OPTIONS
  - HEAD
  - DELETE
debug: true

This is config that i have set in gatekeeper config apart from above mention options.

Comment: If you intercept the request, does it include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Comment: yes. Its showing  Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Comment: Here my issue is now that browser not able to load authentication page of keycloak, when secured resource is called. The auth request is visible in browser network tab.